# изменение родительской части дочернего класса

Tags: java

Не могу решить такую проблему:
Есть 2 класса

```
public class A{
boolean aaa;
}

public class B extends A{
boolean bbb;
}

public B b = new B();
public A a = new A();
```

Как можно сделать так, чтобы родительская составляющая класса В указывала туда же, куда указывает А?

Comment: что значит *родительская составляющая*?

Comment: Как я понимаю, раз В расширяет А, значит внутри В есть А, которую и нужно изменить. Скорее всего путаюсь в терминологии...

Comment: Расширяет это образно.

Comment: В является отдельным объектом, который расширяет _функциональность_ А. Вы создали два объекта - объект класса А и объект класса В, то, куда они указывают, никак не связано между собой.

Comment: @ensom, под расширение понимается функциональность, то есть методы, поля класса

Comment: Суть ясна, всем спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

По сути это два класса.

Понимаете для объектов каждого нового класса будет выделена своя память в куче.
Т.е поля а.ааа и b.ааа будут ссылаться на различные участки памяти. Чтобы а.ааа и b.ааа указывали на одну область это должно быть одним объектом

```
public B b = new B();
public A a = b;
```

либо статическим полем в общем классе.

```
public class A{
   static boolean aaa;
}

public class B extends A{

}

public B b = new B();
public A a = new A();

b.aaa == a.aaa
```